# selecting multiple items from the list and changing their color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, list, text, swiftui

I'm looking for a way to solve this problem in a similar way to this. Is it possible at all?

For a single item no problem. the selected item will be in white the rest of my own color "listTextColor". However, is it possible in a similar way that the elements selected and saved in the "selectedItems" array are displayed in white and the rest in a different color?

example codes:

```
 @State var recordArray: Array = arrayRecords
 @State var selectedItems: Array = []
 @State var selections: String?

List() {
                            ForEach(self.recordArray, id: \.self) { record in
                                Text(record)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.selections = record
                                        self.selectedItems.append(record)
                                        
                                }
                                .foregroundColor(self.selections == record ? Color(.white) : Color(self.listTextColor2))
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Append/remove record.id into selectedItems and check if current record id is in array.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a View Model instead of plain string and use a flag in it to color the row.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var recordArray: [RecordItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach(0..<self.recordArray.count, id: \.self) { i in
                VStack {
                    Text(self.recordArray[i].title)
                }
                .border(Color.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.recordArray[i].isSelected.toggle()
                    self.recordArray[i] = self.recordArray[i]
                }
                .foregroundColor(self.recordArray[i].isSelected ? Color(.red) : Color(.green))
            }
        }
    }
}


class RecordItem {
    var title = ""
    var isSelected = false
}
```

Comment: but it's going to color all Text in List. I want to color only "taped" items. Then it's should look like cheeked in List.

Comment: The above code only colors the tapped items. Did you try it out?

Comment: I found other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this problem.

```
 @State var recordArray: Array = arrayRecords
 @State var selectedItems: Array = []
 @State var selections: String?

var body: some View {
List() {
                            ForEach(self.recordArray, id: \.self) { record in
                                Text(record)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                                                                   if self.selectedItems.first(where: { $0 as! String == record } ) != nil {
                                            self.selectedItems.removeAll(where: { $0 as! String == record } )
                                        } else {
                                            self.selectedItems.append(record)
                                        }
                                        
                                }
                                .foregroundColor((self.selectedItems.first(where: { $0 as! String == record } ) != nil) ? Color(.white) : Color(self.listTextColor2))
                            }
                        }
}
```